# OpenSSL make failure "error: x86_64: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, gcc, openssl

```
# make
making all in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory '/1/openssl-1.0.2f/crypto'
/usr/bin/perl ../util/mkbuildinf.pl "cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM" "darwin64-x86_64-cc" >buildinf.h
cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
<builtin>: recipe for target 'cryptlib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/1/openssl-1.0.2f/crypto'
Makefile:284: recipe for target 'build_crypto' failed
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

So what do I need to do?

I tried compiling with mingw64 and mingw.

---

```
# ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr
Configuring for darwin64-x86_64-cc
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default] 
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =cc
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86_64cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =x86_64-gcc.o x86_64-mont.o x86_64-mont5.o x86_64-gf2m.o rsaz_exp.o rsaz-x86_64.o rsaz-avx2.o
EC_ASM        =ecp_nistz256.o ecp_nistz256-x86_64.o
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes-x86_64.o vpaes-x86_64.o bsaes-x86_64.o aesni-x86_64.o aesni-sha1-x86_64.o aesni-sha256-x86_64.o aesni-mb-x86_64.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-x86_64.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-x86_64.o sha256-x86_64.o sha512-x86_64.o sha1-mb-x86_64.o sha256-mb-x86_64.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86_64.o cmll_misc.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86_64.o aesni-gcm-x86_64.o
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =/usr/bin/ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl
SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode
DES_UNROLL used
DES_INT used
RC4_CHUNK is unsigned long
```

Comment: try changing `-arch x86_64` by `-march x86_64`

Comment: in the makefile I suppose

Comment: No, `-arch` is especially for Darwin for the so called "fat" files. You can give GCC several different architectures this way and a binary running on all. It is most probably something different

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 17):

if you are using linux then :-

```
$ ./Configure LIST | grep -i linux

$ ./Configure linux-x86_64 --prefix=/usr
```

then again use your cmd :-

```
$ make
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> # ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr
> Configuring for darwin64-x86_64-cc
> ```

You are configuring for 64-bit OS X.

> so need to do? i tried compile with mingw64 and mingw

To configure for MinGW or MinGW64:

```
$ ./Configure LIST | grep -i mingw
    mingw
    mingw64
```

So you need to configure using:

```
./Configure mingw64 --prefix=/usr
```

---

If you are on Linux, then you usually use one of:

```
$ ./Configure LIST | grep -i linux
linux-aarch64
linux-alpha+bwx-ccc
linux-alpha+bwx-gcc
linux-alpha-ccc
linux-alpha-gcc
linux-aout
linux-armv4
linux-elf
linux-generic32
linux-generic64
linux-ia32-icc
linux-ia64
linux-ia64-icc
linux-mips32
linux-mips64
linux-ppc
linux-ppc64
linux-ppc64le
linux-sparcv8
linux-sparcv9
linux-x32
linux-x86_64
linux-x86_64-clang
linux-x86_64-icc
linux32-s390x
linux64-mips64
linux64-s390x
linux64-sparcv9
uClinux-dist
uClinux-dist64
vxworks-simlinux
```

Comment: @Andrew - You configured for OS X, not MinGW or MinGW-64. If you have additional details, then you should add it to your question by clicking the ***EDIT*** link in the lower left hand corner of the question. You should also *clearly* state what platform you are trying to build on (Linux, OS X, MinGW, Cygwin, etc). I don't think we even know that yet (its why I provided the Linux hints for you).

Comment: I can give you ssh, can you help me?)

Comment: @Andrew - I'll state this one more time since you seemed to have missed it: *"If you have additional details, then you should add it to your question by clicking the EDIT link in the lower left hand corner of the question. You should also clearly state what platform you are trying to build on"*.